# Vim Ctrl+g = see current function name

Tags: vim

You know how we can get information about the current file with Ctrl+g. I would like to extend that to show the current function name the cursor is currently in. Assume C language.

Any Vim pros out there to help me out?

Comment: You would like it to show the name of the function you're currently "in"? Or?

Comment: vim mailing lists & irc is a better place to ask, I would say.

Comment: @Idigas, yes, the function cursor is in, currently.

Answer (score 1):

`map . :call getline(search("^[^ \t#/]\\{2}.*[^:]\s*$", 'bW')) <CR> %%b`

then input `.` will show "the current function name the cursor is currently in"

Answer (score 0):

You must really have large functions.

I see two ways to do that:

1. by folding with the cursor on a blank line, it will fold the entire current function, letting you see its name. `za` to fold, look at the name, `za` to unfold.
2. by using either [TagList](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273) or [TagBar](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3465), invoking either of these plugins will create a split window with an outline of your file and the cursor positioned on the current function's name and the name highlighted. If your cursor is on a member's name it will show the member instead so you may have to move your cursor over a keyword like `int` or on some whitespace.